# How do i show pushtime out on omni channel widget

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, omnichannel

My routing configuration has a push time out of 60 seconds.I want to achieve the below things

1. i want to show a timer that runs down from 60 seconds to 0 in the omni channel widget just to indicate my agent that they have 60 seconds to accept the work item.
2. My omni channel widget shows a timer that indicates how long a work item has been waiting to be assigned, could it be removed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At this point the only thing you can change within the Omni channel widget are the fields that are visible for each work item detail. This can be done by editing the compact layout for that object. Here is a step-by-step to do that in Salesforce Help: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=service_presence_edit_work_item_details_with_compact_layouts.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't. Here is the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386415&type=1) from Salesforce.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.